# IMultipleResults LINQ DBML Classes Not Resolving

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

In my partial class which defines a function which returns the type of IMultipleResults to bring back multiple result shapes from a stored procedure using the classes defined in my *.dbml file, for some reason the `[ResultType(typeof(MyType))]` isn't working.  The `MyType` is saying that it cannot be found.  The function is in the `.cs` file of my `.dbml` file, and the type is definitely in my dbml file.

Any ideas on why it can't find it?  Here's an idea:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using System.Reflection;

namespace IntranetMvcAreas
{
  partial class ContractsControlDataContext : DataContext
  {
    [Function(Name = "dbo.procCC_Contract_Select")]
    [ResultType(typeof(Contract))]
    [ResultType(typeof(ContractCostCentre))]
    [ResultType(typeof(tblCC_Contract_Data_Terminal))]
    [ResultType(typeof(tblCC_CDT_Data_Service))]
    [ResultType(typeof(tblCC_Data_Service))]
    public IMultipleResults procCC_Contract_Select(
        [Parameter(Name = "ContractID", DbType = "Int")] System.Nullable<int> ContractID,
        [Parameter(Name = "ResponsibilityKey", DbType = "Int")] System.Nullable<int> ResponsibilityKey,
        [Parameter(Name = "ExpenseType", DbType = "Char")] System.Nullable<char> ExpenseType,
        [Parameter(Name = "SupplierID", DbType = "Int")] System.Nullable<int> SupplierID)
    {
      IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, (MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod()), ContractID, ResponsibilityKey, ExpenseType, SupplierID);
      return (IMultipleResults)result.ReturnValue;
    }
  }
}
```

All types in `typeof` cannot be found, despite being in dbml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spoke way too soon, Intellisense finally picked up.  You have to include the relative using statement against your project. (I've never seen this anywhere), so `using IntranetMvcAreas.Areas.Accounts.Models;` did the trick.